# Can't upload files larger than 97.66 KB in Yii2 Framework with Kartik's FileInput widget

Tags: php, file-upload, yii2

When I try to upload a file larger than 97.66 KB I get this error (translated from spanish):

> "File is too large. Its size cannot exceed 97.66 Kib."

This is my widget setup:

```
Modal::begin([
            //'title'=>'File Input inside Modal',
            'header' => 'Agregar foto',
            'toggleButton' => [
                'label'=>'Agregar foto',
                'class'=>'btn btn-default',
                //'href' => Url::to(['afiliado/foto']),
                'value' => Url::to('index.php?r=afiliado/foto&id=' . $model->id),
            ],
        ]);
        echo $form->field($model, 'image')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
            'options' => ['accept' => 'image/*'],
            'pluginOptions'=>[
                'maxFileCount' => 1,
                'allowedFileExtensions'=>['jpg','jpeg','gif','png'],
                'showUpload' => false,
                'maxImageWidth' => 2400,
                'maxImageHeight' => 2400,
                'resizeImage' => true,
                'maxFilePreviewSize' => 10240,
                'minImageWidth' => 50,
                'minImageHeight'=> 50,
                'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                'maxFileSize' => 1024
            ],
        ]);
        Modal::end();
```

And in My php.ini, I set:

```
upload_max_filesize = 99MB
post_max_size = 100MB
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is your model code you need to add the `rules()` set there for the field `image` here in your question

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam that was the problem! I had to also change the rules() method, which was set to 100000. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the file using `UploadedFile::getInstance('image')`, and change you model rules to use `maxSize` around `1024 * 1024 * 100` to set limit around `100MB`

```
[['image'],
   'file',
   'skipOnEmpty' => false,
   'extensions' => 'jpg, png, gif, jpeg',
   'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024 * 100,
   'tooBig' => 'The file was larger than 100MB. Please upload a smaller file.',
],
```